# Is an 120V LED light bulb compatible with a 220V mains?

Tags: led, voltage, light

Would an excellent LED light bulb like the [Cree 60 Watt Replacement TW Series](http://www.creebulb.com/Products/Standard_A-Type/60_Watt_Replacement_TW_Series_Soft_White_LED_Bulb) (designed for the US market) work in European countries?

On the packaging it says "Use only on 120 volt AC circuits." and on the light-bulb itself it says "120V~, 60Hz and 112mA."

The trouble is of course that the light bulb was designed for 120V mains voltage, while in most European countries the voltage is 220V-240V. This is a [high-quality LED bulb](http://www.designingwithleds.com/measuring-light-quality-philips-cree-led-bulbs-spectrometer/) (93 [CRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_rendering_index) and an R9 of 60), and the model is unavailable for European voltages.

So is such an LED at all compatible with a 220V mains country? And if not, how can one work around this limitation?

---

Added - RM:

I'd post this in answer but that's not possible.

As can be seen, main capacitor is 315 VDC rated. The brand is a good one but the voltage from clean 230 VAC and spikes or surges could easily destroy it.

[Excellent teardown report here](http://www.ledsmagazine.com/articles/2013/04/cree-60w-led-replacement-bulb-review-and-tear-down.html)
[Images are from this very good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6DDFRBrSas)

[image]

Top side.
Black 4 led IC is a bridge which rectifies mains and drives 6562 PFC IC. At 110 VAC the DC out of the PFC IC is 220 VDC at full LED brightness. As 230 VAC will rectify to far more than this the unit would be unable to reduce the DC rail low enough.

[image]

Comment: That would depend on the internal circuitry. There is a way to make one that would work on both, but it would require extra effort to design.

Comment: The question might be better asked on: [http://diy.stackexchange.com/](http://diy.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Cree do not appear to have made the voltage range available in std documentation. Various people who hav looked at t suggest 110 VAC nominal only. It makes 120 VDC internally and runs the LEDs from that .| A std 230 V to 110 V transformer would providethe correct voltage. Power is small so transformer would be lowish cost.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon When I look at the packaging, Cree indicates: "Use only on 120 volt AC circuits." On the light-bulb itself it indicates 120V~, 60Hz and 112mA.

Comment: @landroni knowing that would have saved me a substantial amount of searching - I could not find that anywhere on-web. It is essentially certain that Cree will provide an equivalent lamp for 230 VAC operation. | Plugging the bulb into 230 VAC directly MIGHT work but probably would instead result in instant destruction. Numerous possible failure modes exist: > Tear-down reports say that the internal electronic switch is rated at 400 V and rectified 230V mains comes close to that. > Capacitors may well be too low voltage. > If the controller cannot "back off" the PFC converter enough... > & more.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Sorry. I thought just including 120V in the post was sufficient, but I was wrong. As for using the bulb, what about the following workaround: Use the 120V Cree with a 250V lamp connected to a voltage converter outputting 120V (even though the mains itself is 230V). Would that work?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon "It makes 120 VDC internally and runs the LEDs from that." Do you have a reference for that? If it's indeed so, then the bulb is truly excellent: if understand correctly, it internally removes any and all possible flickering coming from the 60Hz frequency of the mains.

Comment: Unless it flickers at 120Hz instead.

Comment: **What part of "use only on 120V" isn't clear?**

Comment: @Kaz I don't trust that much such indications by manufacturers on light-equipment. I still find lamps written in bold "Don't use a bulb over 40 watt", even though a 40 watt CFL would likely fry it to the ground. And last I checked a 250V lamp was being used on a 120V mains, so I'm better off asking those in the know about what "use only on 120V" actually means (and when it is not applicable).

Comment: @Kaz The information in the question re 120VAC only was added by me (although supplied by the user). And Landroni had noted the likely limitations and asked for solutions. so just repointing out what he's already discussing is at best non-constructive and is, arguably, rude. THe world is full of "do not do xxx" warnings. In some cases they may imply "or you and/or the product may die" but often enough they are to minimise a suppliers obligations or to maximise their profits. Knowing if what is advised makes sense often makes sense.

Comment: @landroni the 120 VDC was a typo and should have been 220VDC :-) - which is still good. They use a Power Factor Correction circuit to upconvert to a constant 220 VDC at full brightness and about 205VDC at cutoff. Information came from [This teardown" report about the bulb](http://www.ledsmagazine.com/articles/2013/04/cree-60w-led-replacement-bulb-review-and-tear-down.html). Also goodish is [This teardown video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6DDFRBrSas). There are 20 LEDs with 3 die per pkg = 60 LEDs effective. All in series gives ~3V x 60 = 180V (or 198V at 3V3/LED. ...->

Comment: ... So the 220 VDC gives modest headroom and is varied.   | From video you can see that the main PFC capacitor is a 315V Nichicon. Perfectly 'clean' 230 VAC will peak rectify to slightly above that - the cap may survive it, but the PFC supply "would be perplexed". || Best solution - 110 VAC power (transformer probably) or wait for their 230 VAC version.

Comment: Actually, 230V after passing bridge rectifier will becomes one-directional pulsating voltage with 324V amplitude. So no, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as far as I can see in the linked pages, Cree does not specify the allowed input voltages. Unless you can find markings on the light or its packaging indicating that it will function on 240V as well as 120V, I have to assume that it was designed for 120V only. In that case, plugging it directly into European mains voltage may well destroy the electronics in the bulb and possibly even cause a fire.

The only known safe way to use this in Europe would be with a step-down transformer.

Comment: Unless it's also frequency-sensitive. In which case it could also blow up.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams , can you give an example of something that would be damaged by a different frequency of mains supply ?  In general 50 Hz is considered worse than 60 Hz due to smoothing capacitor voltage droop, but not by much... I have not seen a failure due to frequency in 30 years. I did blow up a surge protected 110vac distribution strip after plugging it in to 240vac... That was Educational.

Comment: Maybe I was being a *bit* dramatic, but the construction of a transformer can limit its use with various frequencies.

Comment: What do you mean by a "step-down transformer"? Could you provide a link showing off an example of such transformer?

Comment: Search for "240V 120V step-down transformer". Example: [http://www.amazon.com/Seven-Star-Watt-240V-120V/dp/B0045RU68U](http://www.amazon.com/Seven-Star-Watt-240V-120V/dp/B0045RU68U)

Comment: @DoxyLover Thanks. Would such a step-down transformer also modify the frequency, from 50Hz (European mains) to 60Hz (expected input by a North American light bulb)?

Comment: No, it cannot change the frequency. As Ignacio later stated, it's unlikely that the bulb will have problems with 50 Hz.